# How to warn users if they are running out of memory in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is there a way we can identify if the device is running out of memory so that we can warn the users in android?

I can see that Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() gives the free memory available in JVM to allocate for the running app. And the below is giving the total space available in the device.

```
   double totalSize = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile().toString()).getTotalSpace();
    double totMb = totalSize / (1024 * 1024);

    Log.d("total Mb memory", String.valueOf(totMb));

    double availableSize = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile().toString()).getFreeSpace();
    double freeMb = availableSize/ (1024 * 1024);

    Log.d("free Mb memory", String.valueOf(freeMb));
```

In order to warn the user, do I have to consider the free memory available in JVM or in the android device?

How does android system allocates memory to each app for runtime? What happens if the app exceeds the allocated runtime space for that app?

where does sqlite and shared preferences store?

Comment: Well there's also prefetch vs truly "free" ram to concern yourself with too, what's this for?

Comment: Your question seems to treat free heap space (RAM) and free disk space as being the same thing. It is not. You may wish to rephrase your question to indicate which of those two is what concerns you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code written in kotlin by me, hope it helps

```
   fun isMemoryLow(): Boolean {
        val memoryInfo = getAvailableMemory()
        return memoryInfo.lowMemory
    }

    private fun getAvailableMemory(): ActivityManager.MemoryInfo {
        val activityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        return ActivityManager.MemoryInfo().also { memoryInfo ->
            activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo)
        }
    }
```